# HTML Form to Google Sheet skip empty rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I follow a tutorial from [this link](https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets) to integrate my form and save the data to a Google sheet. The problem is it doesnt work as I need. I manually add the header at Row 1, but if the sheet has 1000 rows, it will start writing the data from 1001 or so. This is a problem because I use arrayformula to give a unique number based on its rows number. This is my code

```
const sheetName = 'datapokokbaru'
const scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function initialSetup () {
  const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    const headers = sheet.filter(e=>e.join().replace(/,/g, "").length);
    // const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    const nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
    // const nextRow = sheet.length + 1

    const newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

I need the script to check if the rows are not empty then write the data jus after that row number.

Comment: Yeah the array formula is messing up the getLastRow() calculation.  I would avoid the use of formulas altogether.

Comment: I've tested it and confirm that your comment to be TRUE. any suggestion for me to make the unique numbering?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your Spreadsheet from `use arrayformula to give a unique number based on its rows number.`. Can you provide the information for correctly imagining your current Spreadsheet?

Comment: For the meantime, the best for me is using another sheet and do importrange of the first sheet. Thus I can use arrayformula without making the script detect the wrong last Row